# Jenkins fails to build visual Studio project that runs a batch file in its post build event

Tags: jenkins

I'm new to Jenkins and beginning to setup Jenkins.

I have a Visual Studio project which build fine with post build event that runs a batch script file (copy some files).

However when i build the poject via Jenkins using MSBuild it fails to build the project.

I have also tried to build the project by opening the solution/project from Jenkins workspace and it still fails.

I have no clue as to why this would fails.

Any suggestions or help ?

Post build Event set in visual studio:

```
call "$(ProjectDir)..\..\dependencies\scripts\postbuild\ExternalStandard.bat" "$(ProjectDir)..\" "$(TargetDir)" "$(Configuration)"
call "$(ProjectDir)..\..\dependencies\scripts\postbuild\CopyDependenciesInternalLicensing.bat" "$(ProjectDir)..\" "$(TargetDir)" "$(Configuration)"
```

Jenkins build Error:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "call" with "cmd /c". "Call" is typically used inside batch files.

Comment: i have replaced "call" with "cmd /c" yet the build still fails with same error as mentioned above.